# Creating new conversion specifier in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, conversion-specifier

In python we have conversion specifier like

```
'{0!s}'.format(10)
```

which prints

```
'10'
```

How can I make my own conversion specifiers like

```
'{0!d}'.format(4561321)
```

which print integers in following format

```
4,561,321
```

Or converts it into binary like

```
'{0!b}'.format(2)
```

which prints

```
10
```

What are the classes I need to inherit and which functions I need to modify? If possible please provide a small example.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could however do: `'{0!b}'.format(MyInt(2))` and obtain that by implementing the [`__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) special method.

Comment: @Bakuriu what will MyInt() be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is impossible, because built-in types cannot be modified and literals always refer to built-in types.

There is a special method to handle the formatting of values, that is [`__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__), however it only handles the format string, not the conversion specifier, i.e. you can customize how `{0:d}` is handled but not how `{0!d}` is. The only things that work with `!` are `s` and `r`.

Note that `d` and `b` already exist as format specifiers:

```
>>> '{0:b}'.format(2)
'10'
```

In any case you could implement your own class that handles formatting:

```
class MyInt:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __format__(self, fmt):
        if fmt == 'd':
            text = list(str(self.value))
        elif fmt == 'b':
            text = list(bin(self.value)[2:])
        for i in range(len(text)-3, 0, -3):
            text.insert(i, ',')
        return ''.join(text)
```

Used as:

```
>>> '{0:d}'.format(MyInt(5000000))
5,000,000
>>> '{0:b}'.format(MyInt(8))
1,000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not to make your own and try to use default functions already present in python. You can use,

```
'{0:b}'.format(2)  # for binary
'{0:d}'.format(2)  # for integer
'{0:x}'.format(2)  # for hexadecimal
'{0:f}'.format(2)  # for float
'{0:e}'.format(2)  # for exponential
```

Please refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec for more.